# How to check if application on Google Play would work on other (not own) phone?

Tags: google-play-store, compatibility

Is there a way to (at least approximately) check if an application I have found in Google Play store would work on friend's phone.  I'd rather not suggest an app that would not work on friend's phone.

For example is there a way to check if an application would work on Android 2.3, when my phone has Android 4.1.2?

---

Nowadays Google Play store has (in the web version) "Additional information" section, with table (actually: divs) containing structured information about an app, with the following 'columns': "Updated", "Size", "Installs", "Current Version", "***Requires Android***", "Content Rating".

While usually the information I want is in "Requires Android" field (e.g. '4.0.3 and up', '2.2 and up') sometimes it is just '*Varies with device*', e.g. [SoundHound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.melodis.midomiMusicIdentifier.freemium).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let him try installing it via Playstore. If it's "incompatible by design" (e.g. requires Android 4.x while he has only 2.3), Playstore would refuse to install it and give the hint "not compatible with your device".

Apart from that (and if the app description doesn't give a clue):

- check the comments for hints (take care for their date, compared with the "last updated" timestamp of the app; [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) lists the history of an app nicely on its "Changelog" tab)
- Install the SDK on your computer, and add the corresponding AVDs to it to test out for yourself
- Ask for the specific app on a forum, whether anyone can confirm it's running on Android X.X.X / the specific device / ...
- Ask the dev (and if doing so, suggest to include such hints with the desc)

Comment: I see that some (all?) apps in Google Play have "Additional information" table with "Requires Android" column... though it is sometimes 'Varies with device'

Comment: Exactly that's the problem: You can't conclude anything from "varies". And sometimes everything "varies": Android version, size... I wonder whether permissions also vary then. So though you might look there, you not always can rely on that.